# circular cross correlation between two matrices not two vectors

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The following matlab function calculates the circular cross correlation between two vectors:

```
function [ h ] = cxcorr_fft( a,b )
%CXCORR_FFT Calculates the circular cross correlation of the two input vectors using the fft based method
% calculate cross correlation
e = fft(a);
f = fft(b);

 
g = f.*conj(e);
 
h = fftshift(ifft(g));
 
end
```

I have used this function to calculate the circular cross correlation between two images, by replacing the fft by fft2 as follows:

```
function [ h ] = cxcorr_fft( a,b )
%CXCORR_FFT Calculates the circular cross correlation of the two input vectors using the fft based method
% calculate cross correlation
e = fft2(a);
f = fft2(b);
 
g = f.*conj(e);
 
h = fftshift(ifft2(g));
 
end
```

The results are not reasonable. The value of correlation between an image and itself is approximately the same as the value of correlation between an image and a different image. Could you please help me finding the error in the code?

Comment: Why are the results not reasonable? The maximum value of correlation (in the middle of `h`) seems to be as expected. For `a` square with odd size and `b=a`, the values `h((end+1)/2)` and `sum(abs(a(:)).^2)` coincide